# Content of one div to overlap content of another

Tags: css, html

Say I have the following structure:

```
<div id="top" style="width:960px; height:400px; margin 0 auto; background-color:#F00;">
</div>
<div id="bottom" style="width:960px; height:400px; margin 0 auto; background-color:#00F;">
    <div id="overlapingDiv"> Some large content here ...  </div>
</div>
```

How Can I make div with id "overlapingDiv" to come out from "bottom" div 20px and overlap the "top" one so that it will share the background colors of both "top" and "bottom" divs (20px from "top" div and the rest from the "bottom" one)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can float the `overlapingDiv` and then give it a negative margin, e.g.

```
<div id="top" style="width:960px; height:400px; margin 0 auto; background-color:#F00;">
</div>
<div id="bottom" style="width:960px; height:400px; margin 0 auto; background-color:#00F;">
    <div id="overlapingDiv" style="float:left; margin-top: -20px;"> Some content here ...  </div>
</div>​
```

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tgXwC/) sample.

Answer (score 1):

You mean like this?  http://jsfiddle.net/SXRYy/

```
<div id="top" style="width:960px; height:400px; margin 0 auto; background-color:#F00;">
</div>
<div id="bottom" style="width:960px; height:400px; margin 0 auto; background-color:#00F;position: relative">
    <div id="overlapingDiv" style="position: absolute;top: -20px"> Some content here ...  </div>
</div>​
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set a negative top margin:

```
<div id="overlapingDiv" style="margin-top: -20px;"> Some content here ...  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks but top margin moves also the top border of "bottom" div up by 20px too, and I want to move only the "overlapingDiv"

Comment: @koenp's response should do the trick, you need to set position to relative in the parent element and use absolute positioning in the inner elment.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by sharing colors?
If you mean to combine the colors then you will need to use RGBA values for the background colors with CSS

Now, to overlap there are different techniques to overlap divs.
You can use position: relative
You can use negative margins
You can use absolute position, it will depend on what you want to achieve.

Here is a jsfiddle with two overlapping divs merging colors, see if it works for you:
http://jsfiddle.net/8Fnxc/